# Problem on load a PHP page in a div with Shadowbox jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, load, shadowbox

I have a php page call it page.php . In this page I am using the shadowbox effect for opening a new php page (subpage.php)  on it. So I have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  Shadowbox.init();

  $("#configure").click(function(){
    Shadowbox.open({
      content:    $("#hiddenDiv").html(),
      player:     "html",
      title:      "Hello",
      height:     600,
      width:      840
    });
  });

});
```

And then in the html code I am using :

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;">
   <?php include 'subpage.php'; ?>
</div>
```

The shadowbox works ok and I can see the content of subpage.php in it. The problem is that when I am using jQuery code like click(), in the subapage.php it doesn't work. Is like something is wrong with the load if I understood well. Probably the subpage.php is loaded after and this thing doesn't work, something like this.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you do `content:$("#hiddenDiv").html()` you get the contents of the preloaded subpage into a different container. So, after that the elements in this new container aren't bound.

You can automatically rebind them replacing `.click(function() {...})` for `.live('click', function() {...})`

Comment: what attr()? please formulate, or accept this answer and add another question.

Comment: For example when I want to set an attribute like: 
$('#div').attr('checked','checked');
This is not working. Is there something similar I can do for this to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

thats because the click in subpage is not binded. a simple workaround could be to bind the click in the subpage.php file.

Comment: You mean do something like this ?:      
$("#button").bind('click', function(){
        alert("Hello ");
});

Comment: correct. inside the subpage.php, but dont forget to check if domready `$(function(){ $("#button").bind('click', function(){ alert("Hello "); }); });`

Comment: See @ariel's reply, that's what the problem is. As far as jQuery is concerned, it's all one page, because `subpage.php` is included on the server side.