# Can I load the content before Shadowbox opens with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, load, preload, shadowbox

I did a post before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908685/problem-on-load-a-php-page-in-a-div-with-shadowbox-jquery/5908743#5908743)
regarding a problem I had with the shadowbox. In summary, I want to open a subpage.php inside a shadowbox called in page.php.

The problem is that the content of the shadowbox is loaded after the shadowbox.open so I cannot play with some jQuery events in the subpage.php. I noticed for example that if I open once the shadowbox and click a button that should show another box, this thing is not working until I close the shadowbox and open it again.

I am not sure this is the solution, but does anyone know a way to load the shadowbox content before opening it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use JQuery's .load function to pull the content into the container, before you call the shadowbox plugin ?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: This load() thing is not working in my case. I have to use the include (php). Do you have any other idea? Also in shadowbox open I am using content: $("#hiddenDiv").html(), and I think this html() also provokes a problem. Do you know if I can do it differently?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I am surprised .load doesn't work; can you provide your html ?

Comment: I think it has to do with the php page I am trying to show in the shadowbox. I will take a deeper look and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If i interpreted your question correctly. You want to open shadowbox when your page is loaded.

If that is the problem then you can use ajax call or load.

Load:

```
jQuery("#div").load(url,function(){open_shadowbox_function()});
```

your open_shadowbox_function can open a shadowbox for that div.

Ajax:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type:"POST/GET",
   url: url,
   success:function(data){
        jQuery("#div").html(data);
        open_shadowbox_function();
   }

});
```

Hope that helps.